# Bracket/Braces matcher for PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, syntax-highlighting

PyCharm does not appear to have a bracket/braces matcher built-in.  Is there a plugin that would do this for me? I'm looking for something that would highlight or bold the corresponding bracket/brace.

I'm not a fan of the Rainbow Brackets plugin

Comment: There is another useful plugin called `HighlightBracketPair`.

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot? PyCharm highlights opening and corresponding closing brackets by default.

Comment: HighlightBracketPair works great. Thanks halfelf. Putting the cursor one space inside of either bracket/parenthesis seems to do it